# Html head meta tags explanation required?

Tags: html, meta-tags, head

I have seen the following meta tags in many places can anyone explain that are these necessary and how? What do they exactly mean?

```
<meta name="hdl" content="">
<meta name="lp" content="">
<meta name="byl" content="">
<meta name="utime" content="">
<meta name="ptime" content="">
<meta name="pdate" content="">
<meta name="dat" content="">
<meta name="CG" content="">
<meta name="SCG" content="">
<meta name="PT" content="">
<meta name="PST" content="">
<meta name="CN" content="">
<meta name="CT" content="">
<meta name="genre" itemprop="genre" content="">
<meta name="url" itemprop="url" content="">
```

Comment: Perhaps, you want to read this? https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_meta.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look here: https://wiki.whatwg.org/wiki/MetaExtensions
Keep in mind, custom meta tags can be set and don't necessarily have a "general" meaning.